# Why does 'Wheatstone bridge' carries Wheatstone's name when it was invented by someone else?

Tags: electricity

Wheatstone Bridge was invented by Mr. Samuel Hunter Christie. So, How come it carries Mr Charles Wheatstone's name?

I would like to know what each of them contributed toward the 'Wheatstone bridge' besides Mr Samuel inventing it in the first place.

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Hunter_Christie

Comment: "Stigler's law of eponymy, proposed by University of Chicago statistics professor Stephen Stigler in his 1980 publication "Stigler’s law of eponymy",[1] states that no scientific discovery is named after its original discoverer. Examples include Hubble's law which was derived by Georges Lemaître two years before Edwin Hubble, the Pythagorean theorem although it was known to Babylonian mathematicians before Pythagoras, and Halley's comet which was observed by astronomers since at least 240 BC." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy

Comment: @kimchi lover *"In 1833 he published his 'diamond' method, the forerunner of the Wheatstone bridge, in a paper[2] on the magnetic and electrical properties of metals, as a method for comparing the resistances of wires of different thicknesses. However, the method went unrecognised until 1843, when Charles Wheatstone proposed it, in another paper[3] for the Royal Society, for measuring resistance in electrical circuits. Although Wheatstone presented it as Christie's invention, it is his name, rather than Christie's, that is now associated with the device."* This doesn't give the reason WHY ?

Comment: I don't write this as an answer because I'd have to dig too much in my library to find the source, but essentially the reason is that Christie really didn't have a clear understanding of how the bridge works, and Wheatstone was the first to explain its operation in terms of Ohm's law.

Answer (score 1):

This happens all the time -- inventions,  techniques,  diseases, disease *cures*,  all tend to get named for the person who brought them into general use (or simply crushed the competition)

See, for examples,  Edison vs. Tesla,  Baird & Farnsworth vs. Zworkin or Sarnoff,  Apple Computing vs. PARC.

Comment: Your point is correct, but your examples puzzle me - none of those inventors/companies have an eponymous invention or product that I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: @NuclearWang   Kids these days! :-)   ConsolidatedEdison.